# remove ReactiveDict values

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is how I define some ReactiveDict variable:

```
this.templateDictionary = new ReactiveDict();

this.templateDictionary.set( 'type', type );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'size', size );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'bgcolor', bgcolor );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'color', color );
```

Now I want to remove everything:

```
this.templateDictionary.set( 'type', undefined );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'size', undefined );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'bgcolor', undefined );
this.templateDictionary.set( 'color', undefined );
```

But if I do a console.log, I see the variable get the string `undefined`. So it isn't really removed.

And by the way: Is it possible to set multiple values by one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
this.templateDictionary.delete('type');
```

Though printing it out will still show `undefined`, but this is normal.

To delete all keys in your dictionary:

```
this.templateDictionary.clear();
```

For a list of all the functions in `ReactiveDict`, [check this out](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js#L44-L214).

Comment: How can I delete all value, which are saved in this reactiveDict?

Comment: Ahh, yes! clear is what you're after. Answer edited again! delete removes a single key, clear wipes them all out